# How to solve errors in trying to store data from an array of objects in to new one

Tags: arrays, typescript, ionic2

in this code Im trying to `tripID` and `NoteID` from a web service and store them in trips then in other function by reading `trips[i].noteID` cache the other parameters from other web service but fallowing errors happens:

```
public trips= [{ "Token" : "" ,
          "UDI" : "",
          "tripID" : "",
          "NoteID":"",
          "START_ADDRESS":"",
          "END_ADDRESS":"",
          "NAME":"",
          "PHONE":"",
          "COST":"",
         }];

GetTrips(){
  let i = 0;
  let Url='http://mysitesite/gettrip/'+this.UDI+'/'+this.Token;
  console.log(Url);
  this.http.get(Url)
  .map(res => res.json())
            .subscribe(data => {            
          console.log(data);
          for(let note of data.notes) {
            this.trips[i].Token=this.Token;
            this.trips[i].UDI=this.UDI;
            this.trips[i].NoteID=note.ID;
            this.trips[i].tripID=note.TRIP;
            i++;
          }
          console.log(this.trips);
          }
    });
}
```

**errors:**

> EXCEPTION: Cannot set property 'Token' of undefined
>
> EXCEPTION: Cannot set property 'UDI' of undefined
>
> EXCEPTION: Cannot set property'NoteID' of undefined
>
> EXCEPTION: Cannot set property 'tripID' of undefined

**Update 1:**
this is the latest change after @toskv post:

```
for(let note of data.notes) {
        let newTrip = {
            Token: this.Token,
            UDI: this.UDI,
            NoteID: note.ID,
            tripID: note.TRIP,
            START_ADDRESS :null,
            END_ADDRESS:null,
            NAME:null,
            PHONE:null,
            COST:null,
       };
          this.trips.push(newTrip);
          }
          console.log(this.trips);
          this.trips =this.trips.slice(1);
          console.log(this.trips.length);

          }
```

Comment: you should really read a bit about how arrays work in js. right now you are doing undefined.Token inside the for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Getting the value of an index that does not exist in the array will result in the **undefined** value being returned.

Instead you should be pushing new values in the array.

```js
GetTrips() {

  let Url = 'http://mysitesite/gettrip/' + this.UDI + '/' + this.Token;
  console.log(Url);
  this.http.get(Url)
    .map(res => res.json())
    .subscribe(data => {
        console.log(data);

        for (let note of data.notes) {
          let newTrip = {
            Token: this.Token,
            UDI: this.UDI,
            NoteID: note.ID,
            tripID: note.TRIP
          };
          this.trips.push(newTrip);

        }
        console.log(this.trips);
      }
    });
}
```

Comment: Hi @toskv, First of all thank you so much, and next after testing, I've forced to add :` COST:null,END_ADDRESS:null, NAME:null,PHONE:START_ADDRESS:null` to newTrip. then it adds an empty object for 0 index.

Comment: I'm having trouble imagining how that might look like, could you update your question with the code you changed?

Comment: what's with the slice-ing? also in the original post when you defined the trips array you did it with an existing item in it. I'm guessing that's the one you are getting there. Are you trying to define the type of the items in that array?

Comment: hi @toskv could you please check this : i've explained other problem in this page  https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/why-this-happen-functions-do-not-return-correctly/88585